# Retrieving metadata form MP3 Files

Tags: java, javafx, metadata, mp3

I have been trying to extract the Image, Author, date, etc from a MP3 file, but failed.

Is there a way to obtain Image and other information from a (audio) file in java/javafx?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of librarys for this problem: Look [javamusictag](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/index.html)

As example from this Documentation you can read the mp3-Info by Tags like:

File sourceFile;

```
MP3File mp3file = new MP3File(sourceFile);
```

You can also read specific tags:

```
ID3v1_1 tag = new ID3v1_1(sourceFile);
ID3v1 tag = new ID3v1(sourceFile);
ID3v2_4 tag = new ID3v2_4(sourceFile);
ID3v2_3 tag = new ID3v2_3(sourceFile);
ID3v2_2 tag = new ID3v2_2(sourceFile);
Lyrics3v2 tag = new Lyrics3v2(sourceFile);
Lyrics3v1 tag = new Lyrics3v1(sourceFile);
```

Comment: i dont know why my answer is voted down. This question shows no code and the user wants that this community produce code snippets he can use. My answer shows a documentation of using a library for his needs. So why is this answer is voted down?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Okay if you said so - i improved the answer.